# Is there a way to prevent repeating the same image in all page of pdf using JsPdf

Tags: jspdf

I am using JsPdf to generate pdf from multiple images, the issue is that I get the same image generated in all pdf files. any idea please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you  for your answer, actually the problem was caused by an option added in the call of the function, it is caused by the option "split".i use the PNG format withount any problem.

Comment: can you please share the before and after code for clear understanding, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using multiple canvases to generate multi-page PDF document, I was originally using the default format (PNG), so after several hours going through my code I decided to change the format to JPEG, what do you know, the problem went away. Here is the call:

```
doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), "JPEG", 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [parameter list](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/35a9bbd524d0a82f0ecca1b6c65e405501907361/plugins/addimage.js#L520) of `addImage()`:

```
    jsPDFAPI.addImage = function(imageData, format, x, y, w, h, alias, compression, rotation)
```

If you add multiple different images but somehow set `alias` to the same for all, jsPDF will reuse the first of those images. This is intended behaviour and reduces the output size.

I recommend to always set `alias` to something unique for unique images. If `alias` is not set, jsPDF will calculate a hash and for large images, this can be quite expensive.

*[Edit, as I can't comment directly to [marwen web's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42384239/7635462) below:
`addImage()` has no option `split`, so I don not know what you mean. Perhaps you can give an example in case other users have the same problem?]*

Comment: thanks @sgelb, actually i was using the option split  to let jspdf, create multiple images , but it seems not working, so i decided to remove the option and it works, but i have an other problem it is about the quality of images , they are striched